# Struts IndexOutOfBoundsException when assign one entity list value to another

Tags: java, struts2

```
List<EntityList> listEntityLists = new ArrayList<EntityList>();
    List<MatchEventLevel2> eventLevel2s = new ArrayList<MatchEventLevel2>();

    public String createView() {
       eventLevel2s = getDaoFactory().getMatchEventLevel2Dao().findAllActive();

       for (int i = 0; i < eventLevel2s.size(); i++) {
            listEntityLists.get(i).setTname(
                        eventLevel2s.get(i).getTeamA().getTeamid().getTname()
                                + "V/S"
                                + eventLevel2s.get(i).getTeamB().getTeamid()
                                        .getTname());
            }
            return CREATE_VIEW;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ERROR;
        }
    }
```

i fetching one list from matchevent and assign some property of that list to `listEntityLists` where it has two property `id` and `tname` and setting its two property.
i debugg my code bebugg pointer moves in for loop and throws  `IndexOutOfBoundsException :  Index: 0, Size: 0` can any one tell me what is the problem?

Comment: You're trying to assign values to a list member that doesn't exist. You cannot assign values to an index higher than actually exists. You need objects in your list to set values on.

Answer (score 2):

Your listEntityLists is empty. You need to fill it before doing get(i) on it.

Comment: hoe can i give size to list?

Comment: By doing `new ArrayList<>(size);` but it's just initialise the capacity of the list and will not create a new Object on each cell of the list. You will need to do it by yourself.

Comment: but this list size is not fix

Comment: That's why I say it just set the initial capacity of the list. It will not populate the list with your `EntityList` object. For this, you need to do `listEntityLists.add(new EntityList());` to actually have an object in your list.